# Julia 1.1.1 Iterators

Tags: package, julia

I was trying to use the Iterators module in Julia, and I am getting

```
v1.1) pkg> add Iterators
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Iterators [a4bce56a]:
 Iterators [a4bce56a] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0-0.1.10, 0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.1] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only 
versions [0.1.0-0.1.10, 0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.1]
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — 
no versions left
```

Am I missing some secret handshake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Iterators` is not an external package but rather a submodule of `Base`. If you want to use it, simply do `using Base.Iterators` and you're good to go. No need to `add` it.

**Correction:** There is, or better was, a package [Iterators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl) which, however, has been deprecated in favor of [IterTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/IterTools.jl). So, if this is really what you're after, than try `] add IterTools` instead.

Comment: Thanks! The fact that Julia TRIES to add it, threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to use iterators, those are in Julia without adding any packages. Documentation for them is [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/index.html). A quick google has not found a Julia package called Iterators, so I'm not fully sure if this is an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks! It's all a bit confusing, but I think I am finding my way around...